# How to verify certificate chain with openssl

Tags: ssl, openssl

I am trying to verify a certificate file with OpenSSL. Can you explain me why `s_client` connection succeeds, but `verify` file with the same certificate chain fails? How can I verify the file?

Note I compiled OpenSSL 1.0.1k myself, it shouldn't be using any distro-specific config. And I provided the same `CAfile` to both commands.

```
$ openssl s_client -CAfile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt -connect www.google.com:443
WARNING: can't open config file: /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 C = US, O = Equifax, OU = Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
verify return:1
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Inc, CN = Google Internet Authority G2
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google Inc, CN = www.google.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=www.google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
 2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
---
    ...
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

If I run it with `-showcerts` argument, it outputs all three certificates sent from server. I concatenated them into file `google.pem`. But the chain can't be verified. See:

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt google.pem
WARNING: can't open config file: /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf
google.pem: C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google Inc, CN = www.google.com
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Applying a patch suggested on https://stackoverflow.com/a/27606964/1823988 doesn't help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found it. `openssl verify` doesn't expect certificate file to contain its chain. Chain needs to be passed with `-untrusted` argument. It works with the same file, trust is still determined by finding a trusted root in `-CAfile`.

```
openssl verify -CAfile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt -untrusted google.pem google.pem
```