# Sauce Connect with Protractor-Cucumber throwing SSL verify error

Tags: ssl, protractor, ssl-certificate, saucelabs, cucumberjs

Trying running Protractor-Cucumber tests on Sauce Labs through Sauce Connect.

On launching the sauce connect tunneling exe using command `sc -u <username> -k`   I get error
 `'SSL verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate:depth=2...'`

I am setting setting proxy initially using -

```
npm config set proxy <proxy addr..>
npm config set https-proxy <proxy addr..>
set HTTP_PROXY=<proxy addr..>
set HTTPS_PROXY=<proxy addr..>
```

What am I doing wrong here

Output from Sauce Connect Doctor -

```
28 Jul 15:36:15 - Sauce Connect 4.3.16, build 2397 a59c79b
28 Jul 15:36:15 - Calling the doctor
INFO: checking if saucelabs.com can be resolved
INFO: resolving 'saucelabs.com' using default system settings...
INFO: can't resolve 'saucelabs.com'
INFO: resolving 'saucelabs.com' using DNS server '10.7.12.7'...
INFO: can't resolve 'saucelabs.com' via DNS server '10.7.12.7'
!!! WARNING: DNS server '10.7.12.7' can NOT resolve 'saucelabs.com'.
!!! WARNING: this will make Sauce Connect unreliable.
INFO: resolving 'saucelabs.com' using DNS server '10.20.220.36'...
INFO: can't resolve 'saucelabs.com' via DNS server '10.20.220.36'
!!! WARNING: DNS server '10.20.220.36' can NOT resolve 'saucelabs.com'.
!!! WARNING: this will make Sauce Connect unreliable.
INFO: resolving 'saucelabs.com' using DNS server '8.8.8.8'...
INFO: can't resolve 'saucelabs.com'
INFO: resolving 'saucelabs.com' using DNS server '8.8.4.4'...
INFO: can't resolve 'saucelabs.com'
INFO: checking 'saucelabs.com' in hosts file...
INFO: 'saucelabs.com' is not in hosts file
INFO: checking if maki76100.miso.saucelabs.com can be resolved
INFO: resolving 'maki76100.miso.saucelabs.com' using default system settings...
INFO: can't resolve 'maki76100.miso.saucelabs.com'
INFO: resolving 'maki76100.miso.saucelabs.com' using DNS server '10.7.12.7'...
INFO: can't resolve 'maki76100.miso.saucelabs.com' via DNS server '10.7.12.7'
!!! WARNING: DNS server '10.7.12.7' can NOT resolve 'maki76100.miso.saucelabs.com'.
!!! WARNING: this will make Sauce Connect unreliable.
INFO: resolving 'maki76100.miso.saucelabs.com' using DNS server '10.20.220.36'...
INFO: can't resolve 'maki76100.miso.saucelabs.com' via DNS server '10.20.220.36'
!!! WARNING: DNS server '10.20.220.36' can NOT resolve 'maki76100.miso.saucelabs.com'.
!!! WARNING: this will make Sauce Connect unreliable.
INFO: resolving 'maki76100.miso.saucelabs.com' using DNS server '8.8.8.8'...
INFO: can't resolve 'maki76100.miso.saucelabs.com'
INFO: resolving 'maki76100.miso.saucelabs.com' using DNS server '8.8.4.4'...
INFO: can't resolve 'maki76100.miso.saucelabs.com'
INFO: checking 'maki76100.miso.saucelabs.com' in hosts file...
INFO: 'maki76100.miso.saucelabs.com' is not in hosts file
INFO: checking if maki77100.miso.saucelabs.com can be resolved
INFO: resolving 'maki77100.miso.saucelabs.com' using default system settings...
INFO: can't resolve 'maki77100.miso.saucelabs.com'
INFO: resolving 'maki77100.miso.saucelabs.com' using DNS server '10.7.12.7'...
INFO: can't resolve 'maki77100.miso.saucelabs.com' via DNS server '10.7.12.7'
!!! WARNING: DNS server '10.7.12.7' can NOT resolve 'maki77100.miso.saucelabs.com'.
!!! WARNING: this will make Sauce Connect unreliable.
INFO: resolving 'maki77100.miso.saucelabs.com' using DNS server '10.20.220.36'...
INFO: can't resolve 'maki77100.miso.saucelabs.com' via DNS server '10.20.220.36'
!!! WARNING: DNS server '10.20.220.36' can NOT resolve 'maki77100.miso.saucelabs.com'.
!!! WARNING: this will make Sauce Connect unreliable.
INFO: resolving 'maki77100.miso.saucelabs.com' using DNS server '8.8.8.8'...
INFO: can't resolve 'maki77100.miso.saucelabs.com'
INFO: resolving 'maki77100.miso.saucelabs.com' using DNS server '8.8.4.4'...
INFO: can't resolve 'maki77100.miso.saucelabs.com'
INFO: checking 'maki77100.miso.saucelabs.com' in hosts file...
INFO: 'maki77100.miso.saucelabs.com' is not in hosts file
INFO: checking if maki78100.miso.saucelabs.com can be resolved
INFO: resolving 'maki78100.miso.saucelabs.com' using default system settings...
INFO: can't resolve 'maki78100.miso.saucelabs.com'
INFO: resolving 'maki78100.miso.saucelabs.com' using DNS server '10.7.12.7'...
INFO: can't resolve 'maki78100.miso.saucelabs.com' via DNS server '10.7.12.7'
!!! WARNING: DNS server '10.7.12.7' can NOT resolve 'maki78100.miso.saucelabs.com'.
!!! WARNING: this will make Sauce Connect unreliable.
INFO: resolving 'maki78100.miso.saucelabs.com' using DNS server '10.20.220.36'...
INFO: can't resolve 'maki78100.miso.saucelabs.com' via DNS server '10.20.220.36'
!!! WARNING: DNS server '10.20.220.36' can NOT resolve 'maki78100.miso.saucelabs.com'.
!!! WARNING: this will make Sauce Connect unreliable.
INFO: resolving 'maki78100.miso.saucelabs.com' using DNS server '8.8.8.8'...
INFO: can't resolve 'maki78100.miso.saucelabs.com'
INFO: resolving 'maki78100.miso.saucelabs.com' using DNS server '8.8.4.4'...
INFO: can't resolve 'maki78100.miso.saucelabs.com'
INFO: checking 'maki78100.miso.saucelabs.com' in hosts file...
INFO: 'maki78100.miso.saucelabs.com' is not in hosts file
!!! ERROR: can't resolve 3/3 tunnel hostname(s) via any DNS server.
!!! ERROR: please check your firewall and DNS settings.
INFO: checking if connecting to Sauce Labs REST API via SSL works
!!! ERROR: SSL connect failed, socket: 908, code: 5.
INFO: checking if accessing https://saucelabs.com/rest/v1 works
INFO: resolving 'saucelabs.com' using default system settings...
INFO: can't resolve 'saucelabs.com'
INFO: resolving 'saucelabs.com' using DNS server '10.7.12.7'...
INFO: can't resolve 'saucelabs.com' via DNS server '10.7.12.7'
!!! WARNING: DNS server '10.7.12.7' can NOT resolve 'saucelabs.com'.
!!! WARNING: this will make Sauce Connect unreliable.
INFO: resolving 'saucelabs.com' using DNS server '10.20.220.36'...
INFO: can't resolve 'saucelabs.com' via DNS server '10.20.220.36'
!!! WARNING: DNS server '10.20.220.36' can NOT resolve 'saucelabs.com'.
!!! WARNING: this will make Sauce Connect unreliable.
INFO: resolving 'saucelabs.com' using DNS server '8.8.8.8'...
INFO: can't resolve 'saucelabs.com'
INFO: resolving 'saucelabs.com' using DNS server '8.8.4.4'...
INFO: can't resolve 'saucelabs.com'
INFO: checking 'saucelabs.com' in hosts file...
INFO: 'saucelabs.com' is not in hosts file
INFO: URL https://saucelabs.com/versions.json can be reached
INFO: resolving 'saucelabs.com' using default system settings...
INFO: can't resolve 'saucelabs.com'
INFO: resolving 'saucelabs.com' using DNS server '10.7.12.7'...
INFO: can't resolve 'saucelabs.com' via DNS server '10.7.12.7'
!!! WARNING: DNS server '10.7.12.7' can NOT resolve 'saucelabs.com'.
!!! WARNING: this will make Sauce Connect unreliable.
INFO: resolving 'saucelabs.com' using DNS server '10.20.220.36'...
INFO: can't resolve 'saucelabs.com' via DNS server '10.20.220.36'
!!! WARNING: DNS server '10.20.220.36' can NOT resolve 'saucelabs.com'.
!!! WARNING: this will make Sauce Connect unreliable.
INFO: resolving 'saucelabs.com' using DNS server '8.8.8.8'...
INFO: can't resolve 'saucelabs.com'
INFO: resolving 'saucelabs.com' using DNS server '8.8.4.4'...
INFO: can't resolve 'saucelabs.com'
INFO: checking 'saucelabs.com' in hosts file...
INFO: 'saucelabs.com' is not in hosts file
INFO: URL https://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/myuserid/tunnels can be reached
INFO: checking if accessing http://google.com works
INFO: resolving 'google.com' using default system settings...
INFO: can't resolve 'google.com'
INFO: resolving 'google.com' using DNS server '10.7.12.7'...
INFO: can't resolve 'google.com' via DNS server '10.7.12.7'
!!! WARNING: DNS server '10.7.12.7' can NOT resolve 'google.com'.
!!! WARNING: this will make Sauce Connect unreliable.
INFO: resolving 'google.com' using DNS server '10.20.220.36'...
INFO: can't resolve 'google.com' via DNS server '10.20.220.36'
!!! WARNING: DNS server '10.20.220.36' can NOT resolve 'google.com'.
!!! WARNING: this will make Sauce Connect unreliable.
INFO: resolving 'google.com' using DNS server '8.8.8.8'...
INFO: can't resolve 'google.com'
INFO: resolving 'google.com' using DNS server '8.8.4.4'...
INFO: can't resolve 'google.com'
INFO: checking 'google.com' in hosts file...
INFO: 'google.com' is not in hosts file
INFO: URL http://google.com can be reached
INFO: checking if accessing https://google.com works
INFO: resolving 'google.com' using default system settings...
INFO: can't resolve 'google.com'
INFO: resolving 'google.com' using DNS server '10.7.12.7'...
INFO: can't resolve 'google.com' via DNS server '10.7.12.7'
!!! WARNING: DNS server '10.7.12.7' can NOT resolve 'google.com'.
!!! WARNING: this will make Sauce Connect unreliable.
INFO: resolving 'google.com' using DNS server '10.20.220.36'...
INFO: can't resolve 'google.com' via DNS server '10.20.220.36'
!!! WARNING: DNS server '10.20.220.36' can NOT resolve 'google.com'.
!!! WARNING: this will make Sauce Connect unreliable.
INFO: resolving 'google.com' using DNS server '8.8.8.8'...
INFO: can't resolve 'google.com'
INFO: resolving 'google.com' using DNS server '8.8.4.4'...
INFO: can't resolve 'google.com'
INFO: checking 'google.com' in hosts file...
INFO: 'google.com' is not in hosts file
INFO: URL https://google.com can be reached
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more information about what OS (I suspect Windows) and what version of SC you're using.

Also running the Sauce Connect with `-vv --doctor` command line arguments and posting the output may help with the diagnosis.

Also, review this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599985/verify-errorcode-20-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate) for reference.

Comment: Updated question with output from running '--doctor' command. OS - Windows. SC version - 4.3.16

Comment: I have a "feeling" your proxy settings are not correct and you're having trouble reaching Sauce Labs. Also I'd check if your proxy let's you access sauce labs. Here's some sample code for independent verification https://github.com/mehmetg/proxy-test-js

Comment: Talk to your network people IT/Security team. They may need to white list the IP range. First of all test it out on your own make sure that's the issue.